# Prove by Mathematical Induction that $(-1)^{1}+(-1)^{2}+(-1)^{3}+⋯+(-1)^{n}=\frac{(-1)^{n}-1}{2}$

Tags: proof-explanation, induction

Prove by PMI that:

$(-1)^{1}+(-1)^{2}+(-1)^{3}+⋯+(-1)^{n}=\frac{(-1)^{n}-1}{2}$

Induction Hipotesis for some integer k:

$(-1)^{1}+(-1)^{2}+(-1)^{3}+⋯+(-1)^{k}=\frac{(-1)^{k}-1}{2}$

Induction Step:

$(-1)^{1}+(-1)^{2}+(-1)^{3}+⋯+(-1)^{k}+(-1)^{k+1}=\frac{(-1)^{k+1}-1}{2}$

So we have:

$\frac{(-1)^{k}-1}{2}+(-1)^{k+1}=\frac{(-1)^{k+1}-1}{2}$

Working with LHS:

$\frac{(-1)^{k}-1}{2}+(-1)^{k+1}=\frac{(-1)^{k}-1+2(-1)^{k+1}}{2}$

$=\frac{(-1)^{k}-1+2(-1)^{k+1}}{2}$

$=\frac{(-1)^{k}[2(-1)^{1}+1]-1}{2}$

I'm not sure how to proceed since $2(-1)^{1}+1=-1$, so LHS will end up being $=\frac{-(-1)^{k}-1}{2}$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And $-(-1)^k=(-1)^{k+1}$.

Comment: Aha, I forgot to multiply. So $-(-1)^{k}-1=(-1)^{1}(-1)^{k}-1=(-1)^{k+1}-1$. Thanks!

Comment: Do you HAVE to use mathematical induction? The reason I ask is that if this is simply an identity you want to verify for some reason, then it's much simpler to prove this in two cases -- $n$ is even and $n$ is odd. To use computer jargon, I'm wondering whether this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). (My guess is it's NOT an XY Problem because this is a course or textbook exercise, but since you didn't provide any context for this . . .)

Answer (score 1):

Hi I would first of all rewrite the task to

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i}=\frac{(-1)^n-1}{2}$$

So at first for n=1 the statement is correct since

$$(-1)^1=\frac{(-1)^1-1}{2}$$

Then the induction step is then for all $n\geq 1$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} (-1)^k=\sum_{i=1}^{n} (-1)^k+(-1)^{n+1}$$
$$=\frac{(-1)^n-1}{2}+(-1)^{n+1}=\frac{(-1)^n-1}{2}+\frac{2(-1)^{n+1}}{2}$$
$$\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(\frac{1}{-1}+2)-1}{2}=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}-1}{2}$$